# cassandra error when using select and where in cql

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a `cassandra` table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test(
id text,
time bigint,
tag text,
mstatus boolean,
lonumb  int,
PRIMARY KEY (id, time, tag)
)
```

And I want to select one column using `select`.
I tried:

```
select * from test where lonumb = 4231;
```

It gives:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator"
```

Also I cannot do

```
select * from test where mstatus = true;
```

Doesn't `cassandra` support `where` as a part of CQL? How to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jny is correct in that `WHERE` is only valid on columns in the PRIMARY KEY, or those where a secondary index has been created for.  One way to solve this issue is to create a specific query table for `lonumb` queries.

```
CREATE TABLE test.testbylonumb(
  id text,
  time bigint,
  tag text,
  mstatus boolean,
  lonumb  int,
  PRIMARY KEY (lonumb, time, id)
)
```

Now, this query will work:

```
select * from testbylonumb where lonumb = 4231;
```

It will return all CQL rows where `lonumb` = 4231, sorted by `time`.  I put `id` on the PRIMARY KEY to ensure uniqueness.

```
select * from test where mstatus = true;
```

This one is trickier.  Indexes and keys on low-cardinality columns (like booleans) are generally considered a bad idea.  See if there's another way you could model that.  Otherwise, you could experiment with a secondary index on `mstatus`, but only use it when you specify a partition key (`lonumb` in this case), like this:

```
select * from testbylonumb where lonumb = 4231 AND mstatus = true;
```

Maybe that wouldn't perform too badly, as you are restricting it to a specific partition.  But I definitely wouldn't ever do a `SELECT *` on `mstatus`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `WHERE` on the indexed or primary key columns. To correct your issue you will  need to create an index.

```
CREATE INDEX iname 
ON keyspacename.tablename(columname)
```

You can see more info [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html).

But you have to keep in mind that this query will have to run against all nodes in the cluster.

Alternatively you might rethink your table structure if the `lonumb` is something you'll do the most queries on.

Comment: I'm typically not a fan of secondary indexes.  But it might not be too bad if an index was used in a query where the partition key(s) was also specified.  +1